# I'm trying to create a private variable. The function was supposed to return the value of the private variable 'secret', but it's not. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript

> I'm trying to create a private variable. It was supposed to return the value of the private variable 'secret', but it's not. What's wrong?

```js
"use strict";

function secretCode() {
  var secret = "This is the secret !!!";
  return () => {
    return secret;
  };
}


//console.log(secret);  //This should return Undefined
var getSecret = secretCode();
console.log(getSecret); //this should log "This is the secret !!!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **secretCode** function return **function return secret** instead of return **secret** private variable

Let's add the "()" to your **getSecret** variable:

```js
"use strict";

function secretCode() {
  var secret = "This is the secret !!!";
  return () => {
    return secret;
  };
}


//console.log(secret);  //This should return Undefined
var getSecret = secretCode();
console.log(getSecret()); //this should log "This is the secret !!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

`secretCode()` returns a function.

```
console.log(getSecret());
```